# Show RowDetails on double-click in WPF DataGrid

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

At the moment my DataGrid shows the RowDetails when i click a row. But I want to show the RowDetails only on Double-click.

Any ideas for solving this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

e.g.

```
<DataGrid RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="RowDoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

```cs
private void RowDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var row = (DataGridRow)sender;
    row.DetailsVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed ?
        Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: But another question: Now i want to close all other rows, because I want to allow only one row with details. Is there any way to iterate the rows? Thanks ;)

Comment: That is a bit difficult, you best bet would be to bind the visibility to some property on your items then you can have easier access, if you want to get all the rows you need to use the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms592860.aspx) i think.

Comment: Would you put that code for the event in the MainWindowViewModel or would you put it in the MainWindow.xmal.cs code behind?  I am going to put it into the viewmodel. and see what happens