# How to get the item at the mouse position when I perform a Double Click on DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am new in WPF and I have a question about the DataGrid, how could I get the item at the mouse position when I perform a Double Click on DataGrid?

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you'd like to keep this question around it should have a *proper* answer, to that end i added one now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `DoubleClick` event using a [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx) and an [`EventSetter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter.aspx), for rows use the [`RowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowstyle.aspx), for specific cells the [`CellStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.cellstyle.aspx).

In the handler you can then cast the `sender` to `DataGridRow` or `DataGridCell` respectively.

*([[Example with rows]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6124074/546730))*