# Scrolling the Datagrid firing mouse double click event

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, eventtrigger

I have a `DataGrid` and I want to show another form when the row is double clicked but this event is firing even if I am scrolling the datagrid. How to make it fire only when the row is double clicked?

I am using MVVM pattern.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgScopeRecords" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Model.TableScopeRecords}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Model.SelectedIndex}" Margin="0,10,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewScopeRecordCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#dca188"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static Resources:Translations.RecordsInspection_ColumnScope}" Binding="{Binding Scope.ScopeName}" Width="250"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static Resources:Translations.RecordsInspection_ColumnScopeType}" Binding="{Binding Scope.ScopeType.ScopeTypeName}" Width="100"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123748/show-rowdetails-on-double-click-in-wpf-datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only assume that your `Interaction.Triggers` are causing your problem. I accept that you want to 'convert' that event into a `Command`, but if you implement a standard `MouseDoubleClick` handler instead (just temporarily), you will see that scrolling does *not* fire the handler at all.

You can still convert that event to a `Command` in your own custom `Attached Property`. They are relatively simple to create and you can find out how to do this from the [Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) page at MSDN.

Comment: That is incorrect.  It is the same behavior, because the doubleclick handler is for the entire datagrid.